# Changing input data of each batch during training in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have a Keras model and a given input data set.

I need to modify the input data based on the prediction from the model and a linear programming procedure implemented in Python before each batch training.

It seems that I could do this before each epoch by using a for loop such that:

```
for each epoch:
  train model
  compute prediction based on input data
  new input data = LP(input data, prediction)
  break if epoch=50
```

My question is how to do this before each batch.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check Keras [Callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/) and especially LambdaCallback, It allows you to set function for

- on_epoch_begin: called at the beginning of every epoch.
- on_epoch_end:called at the end of every epoch.
- on_batch_begin: called at the beginning of every batch.
- on_batch_end: called at the end of every batch.
- on_train_begin: called at the beginning of model training.
  on_train_end: called at the end of model training.

Comment: i am not sure if the input data set can be dynamically changed after model.fit is called and data set is loaded into the memory. On top of that, callbacks does not have access to batch data itself. However, it seems that keras.utils.Sequence may do what I think I want to do.